# Is is possible to return virtual attributes automatically in Rails models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, decorator, activemodel, virtual-attribute

Given:

```
class Foo
  has_one :bar

  def bar_name
    bar.name
  end
end

class Bar
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

In the console or in a view, I can `@foo.bar_name` to get `'baz'`.

I'm aware that I can `@foo.as_json(methods: :bar_name)` to get `{"id"=>"abc123", "bar_name"=>"baz"}`.

I could also denormalize the attribute and make it non-virtual, but I would rather not do that in this case.

Is it possible to automatically return the model with the virtual attribute included?

`#<Foo id: "abc123", bar_name: "baz">`

I want to do this because I am constructing a large object with nested collections of models, and the `as_json` call is abstracted away from me.

Comment: I don't understand , you want to send `#<Foo id: "abc123",bar_name: "baz">` to clients or you want `Foo` objects to be printed like that in console(e.g. `puts fooobj # => #<Foo id: "...",bar_name: "baz">` ) ?

Comment: Let's say that I'm not sending anything to a client. I just want the result of the method to be shown in the console without explicitly calling the method.

Comment: Do you want this in the `as_json` response? If so you can just redefine `as_json` in the model itself. If you want this in the object representation you can redefine `inspect`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not 100% sure I understand if your concern is related to `as_json` but if so this will work

```
class Foo
  has_one :bar

  def bar_name
    bar.name
  end
  def as_json(options={})
    super(options.merge!(methods: :bar_name))
  end
end
```

Now a call to `@foo.as_json` will by default include the `bar_name` like your explicit example does.

Ugly would not recommend but you could change the inspection of foo e.g. `#<Foo id: "abc123", bar_name: "baz">` as follows

```
class Foo
  def inspect
    base_string = "#<#{self.class.name}:#{self.object_id} "
    fields = self.attributes.map {|k,v| "#{k}: #{v.inspect}"}
    fields << "bar_name: #{self.bar_name.inspect}"
    base_string << fields.join(", ") << ">"
  end
end
```

Then the "inspection notation" would show that information although I am still unclear if this is your intention and if so why you would want this.

Comment: Yes, that actually solves my real case that I mentioned at the end of my question. Someone actually posted that solution earlier and then deleted it.  But I did still want to know whether or not it was possible to do prior to rendering in a single call. @mmichael seems to have confirmed that it is not.

Comment: What do you mean "prior to rendering" if you want it in the object notation you would have to redefine `inspect`

Comment: I guess I've learned that whether I'm in the console, a view, or receiving json, the inclusion of the virtual attribute is purely a presentational concern. Otherwise, there is no point in "automatically" including it in the return value when I can just make the method call. So the correct answer is something like, "yes, it's possible, but not worth doing when all that I need is to override the `as_json`". Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `attr_accessor` - per the [Rails docs](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor):

> Defines a named attribute for this module, where the name is symbol.id2name, creating an instance variable (@name) and a corresponding access method to read it. Also creates a method called name= to set the attribute.

Comment: Thanks, but that and `attr_reader` don't seem to automatically include the virtual attribute when the object is retrieved. I'm purely asking if I can get that console output without making an explicit call to the method.

Comment: It's not possible to include the virtual attribute without a call to the method. There's also `model.instance_methods`, but that's just a slightly less explicit call. Short of monkey-patching Rails' built-in `attr_accessor`, I'm afraid you're going to have to make that method call.